# Auto-completing lists

Tags: lists

Please, if at all possible, can anyone help with a generic, grand scheme for completing general lists, such as seen below. pgf's `\foreach` can handle some of them, but I have a need for auto-completion outside of `\foreach`. Must one define a completion scheme for each list type, as I am doing now?

```
\def\lista{1,...,10,13,...,21}
\def\lista{1,2,...,10,13,15,...,21}
\def\lista{1pt,2pt,...,10pt,13pt,15pt,...,21pt}
\def\lista{1ex,2ex,...,10ex,13ex,15ex,...,21ex}
\def\lista{a,b,1,...,10,13,...,21}
\def\lista{a,b,1,2,...,10,13,...,21}
\def\lista{1,2,a,b,1,...,10,13,...,21}
\def\lista{A,...,S,a,...,s}
\def\lista{A,B,...,S,a,b,...,s}
\def\lista{A,B,1,...,10,a,b,...,f}
\def\lista{a,A,1,...,10,13,...,21}
\def\lista{2^1,2^2,2^3,...,2^10,a^1,a^2,...,a^9}
\def\lista{1_2,2_2,...,5_2,a_2,b_2,...,h_2}
\def\lista{c_2,d_2,...,e_2}
\def\lista{1\pi,...,3\pi}
\def\lista{0\pi,0.5\pi,...,3\pi}
\def\lista{1^\pi,1.5^\pi,...,5.5^\pi}
```

Completion-wise, a folded list such as

```
\def\lista{1,...,10,13,...,21}
```

is basically the same as

```
{1,...,10}
{13,...,21}
```

Comment: So use of `pgffor` package is allowed?

Comment: Sorry if that was a little too short. What I meant is that one might plug in to `pgffor`'s parser only and hijack the usage. Regarding the overkill, if it doesn't put any burden on the user other than computational load, I tend to think it not as an overkill. Same is commonly done to pick up a symbol from a vast package. Compatibility is indeed another story.

Comment: Also `pgfplots` has a nice table parser too which can differentiate different seperators. So it's not that alienated from what you are looking for if you wish to combine them. Also, your folded list is ambiguous for the parser anyway since it can interpret `10,13,...,21` too which is easy to show with a `\foreach` macro. One shouldn't consider it as an overkill since if this problem is implemented it would almost be like `pgffor` so why double the effort?

Answer (score 3):

Some of those lists (including the one you highlight at the end) I can not guess what the relationship between the entries is. If in each case you wrote down what the relationship was, rather than try to show it by example, your problem would be solved. As your loop would just loop over an integer `\i` going from 1 upwards, then for example your last one is just

```
\makeatletter

\newcount\i
\loop
\advance\i 1

\dimen@=\i\p@
\divide\dimen@ by 2
\advance\dimen@ 0.5\p@
\edef\x{\strip@pt\dimen@^\pi}
\show\x
\iftrue
\repeat
```

which makes:

```
> \x=macro:
->1^\pi .
\iterate ...\x {\strip@pt \dimen@ ^\pi } \show \x 
                                                  \iftrue \relax \expandafte...
l.14 \repeat

? 
> \x=macro:
->1.5^\pi .
\iterate ...\x {\strip@pt \dimen@ ^\pi } \show \x 
                                                  \iftrue \relax \expandafte...
l.14 \repeat

? 
> \x=macro:
->2^\pi .
\iterate ...\x {\strip@pt \dimen@ ^\pi } \show \x 
                                                  \iftrue \relax \expandafte...
l.14 \repeat
```

Comment: Thanks. It’s hard to work out a common denominator/relationship between all of them. I might have been right by approaching each separately, but the implementation appears drawn-out. I thought a *maharishi* would simply wave a magic wand at them. I have used eTeX for all the list types.

Comment: But you have to do that work anyway surely? I can't see how just from enumerating the first few elements of each list any person or software would have any idea what the next element is. Once you have said what the definition of each list is, defining it on TeX should be easy, as I showed for one of the few lists in your example where I could guess the intended pattern.